# Two metrics have the same open sets and the same convergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function that is monotonically increasing with $\lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x)) = c \in \Bbb R$ and let $d(x;y) = |x-y|$ be the usual metric. Let $d_f(x;y) = |f(x)-f(y)|$ be another metric.

Show that $(\Bbb R;d)$ and $(\Bbb R; d_f)$ have the same open sets and the same convergent sequences.

**My idea:**

At first, I show that an open set in $(\Bbb R;d_f)$ is also an open set in $(\Bbb R;d)$.

Let $A$ be an open set in $(\Bbb R;d_f)$ and let be $a \in A$. Then, there is an $\epsilon > 0$ with $B_{\epsilon,d_f}(a) \subseteq A$. Since $f$ is continous, there is a $\delta > 0$ with $B_{\delta,d}(a) \subseteq B_{\epsilon,d_f}(a)$. Thus, $A$ is also an open set in $(\Bbb R;d)$.

But how to show the other direction?

Comment: This is not true.  Consider $f$ a constant function.

Comment: Thank you, that' s right. I forgot to mention that it' s monotically increasing.